# User session tracking with replays/recordings on webgl/canvas

Tags: session, webgl, tracking

Does any one know of any user session tracking software like HotJar or Lucky Orange that record webgl/canvas video?

All the ones I have tried simply show a black screen when recording. Any HTML rendered above is fine, but the  itself is blank.

Answer (score 1):

on lucky orange, this can be done with

```
LO.update_canvas("canvas")
```

on event(click, mousedown, touchstart
    ,mousemove ,touchmove
    ,mouseup ,touchend, mouseleave)